# AdMob Ads are valid for how much time after loaded successfully?

Tags: admob, interstitial, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad, firebase-admob

I wanted to know that...
if we have loaded any AdMob ads (Interstitial Ads, Rewarded Ads).
then **how much time it is valid to show?**

> **Is there any time limit define to show ads after loaded?**